# Python BeautifulSoup: Text from the html (web) page not shown while soup.find_all(..)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was studying data scraping for IndiaBix.com, I was trying to fetch all the questions along with their options and answers. I was successful in getting the questions and the options but I was unable to fetch the answer. The answer format looks like below:

```
<div class="div-spacer">
                        <p><span class="ib-green"><b>Answer:</b></span> Option <b class="jq-hdnakqb">A</b></p> 
                        <p><span class="ib-green"><b>Explanation:</b></span></p> 
                        <p> No answer description available for this question. <b><a href="discussion-553">Let us discuss</a></b>. </p> 
                    </div>
```

In the code

```
<b class="jq-hdnakqb">A</b>
```

for this line, the text 'A' is not getting fetched by the parser.

The IndiaBix page link is as follows:
[Click here](http://www.indiabix.com/computer-science/operating-systems-concepts/013001)

In browser InspectElement text 'A' is visible whereas that parser is not fetching the text in beautifulSoup.

Kindly help me with this. I am new to python.

Comment: There's JavaScript involved. That's probably why.

Comment: @jDo Is there any way to view that?

Comment: When I go to the site you've linked to and hover over the "View Answer" button, the link (shown in the lower left corner of the browser window) says `javascript: void(0);`. Also, I use NoScript so it's pretty easy to see on my end (anything that doesn't work out-of-the-box depends on JavaScript). Sometimes, you can fetch the data straight via the API - this is probably the cleanest solution. If not, there are "robot browsers" (phantomJS and selenum, for instance) that can handle these things.

Comment: @jDo Thanks. I am able to view in my browser, but when I am reading the parsing the page using beautifulsoup, the text 'A' is not getting displayed. Will there be any problem with my parser? I was using 'html.parser'

Comment: I see now that the answers are also being generated by JavaScript. It's pretty easy to parse the html and extract the answer divs but the actual answers (`<b class="jq-hdnakqb">A</b>`) aren't extracted. You'll need to look at the JavaScript and figure out how it creates the "A" in the `<b>` element.

Comment: @jDo Thanks a lot. Could you please help me out with that? I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: It's most likely found [here](http://www.indiabix.com/_files/js/js-alpha-009.js). Look for the relevant identifiers/selectors in the html and try to "reverse" how they're populated with data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110832/discussion-between-jeril-and-jdo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a collaborative effort. I used [alecxe's BeautifulSoup gist](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/729d566b7423c799a09b9e7fdc46b3f9) to fetch and pretty-print the questions, and then I did the de-obfuscation necessary to get the answers:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.indiabix.com/computer-science/operating-systems-concepts/013001"
data = requests.get(url, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
}).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

answers_string = soup.findAll("input", {"id":"hdnAjaxImageCacheKey"})[0]["value"]
answers = answers_string[::-1][17:22].upper()

# iterate over questions
for num, question_block in enumerate(soup.select(".bix-div-container")):
    question = question_block.select(".bix-td-qtxt")[0].get_text(strip=True)
    print(question + "\n")

    # iterate over answers
    for answer_block in question_block.select(".bix-tbl-options tr"):
        number, answer = answer_block.select(".bix-td-option")

        print(number.get_text(), answer.get_text())

    print("\nANSWER: " + answers[num])
    print("----")
```

The site does some funky `eval`ing (found in [this](http://www.indiabix.com/_files/js/js-alpha-009.js) script) and fetches the answers from a 40 character string in a hidden input:

```
/* Load Images Indirectly For Better User Experience */
try{eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0 5=l.o.h.2(\'\').8().7(\'\').e("m"+"n"+"q");g(5>-1){0 d=$(\'4\'+\'#\'+\'3\'+\'p\'+\'k\'+\'f\'+\'j\').r().6(C).2(\'\').8().7(\'\').6(B).s().2(\'\');0 c=$(\'4\'+\'.\'+\'a\'+\'-\'+\'3\'+\'D\');0 9=$(\'b\'+\'.\'+\'a\'+\'-\'+\'3\'+\'A\'+\'z\');u.t(d,w(i,v){c[i].x=v;9[i].y=v})}',40,40,'var||split|hdn|input|intPos|substr|join|reverse|arrImageViews|jq||arrImagePorts|arrImageCount|indexOf|Cache|if|href||Key|Image|window|xi|baid|location|Ajax|ni|val|toUpperCase|each|jQuery||function|value|innerHTML|qb|ak|17|18|akq'.split('|')))}catch(err){}
```

Note the silly attempt at misleading the curious visitor via comments :D

```
/* Load Images Indirectly For Better User Experience */
```

When `eval`'ed, simplified, and cut down to size, it looks like this:

```
var arrImageCount=$('input'+'#'+'hdn'+'Ajax'+'Image'+'Cache'+'Key').val().substr(18).split('').reverse().join('').substr(17).toUpperCase().split('');

var arrImagePorts=$('input'+'.'+'jq'+'-'+'hdn'+'akq');

var arrImageViews=$('b'+'.'+'jq'+'-'+'hdn'+'ak'+'qb');

jQuery.each(arrImageCount,function(i,v){arrImagePorts[i].value=v;arrImageViews[i].innerHTML=v})
```

Tip: if you're afraid of `eval`ing random JS (you should be), replace `eval` with `print`.

Anyway, the code is pretty simple. It does the following:

- get the string from the hidden input field
- reverse it
- extract the 5 characters at index 17 to 22
- split them to an array
- add the array contents, i.e. the answers, to the 5 questions on the page using jQuery

This is easily mimicked in Python like so:

```
answers_string = soup.findAll("input", {"id":"hdnAjaxImageCacheKey"})[0]["value"]
answers = answers_string[::-1][17:22].upper()
```

Comment: Awesome investigation!

Comment: @alecxe Thanks :) Let me know if I should remove the link to your gist or if anything else should be changed (I noticed that the gist was marked "secret" after I wrote the answer)

Comment: @jDo Thanks a lot. Just as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the *correct answers are dynamically loaded* and there is *JavaScript involved*.

One option to approach the problem would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) browser automation package with a headless [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'http://www.indiabix.com/computer-science/operating-systems-concepts/013001'
driver.get(url)

# wait for the page to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ib-main-bar")))

# iterate over questions
for question_block in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".bix-div-container"):
    question = question_block.find_element_by_css_selector(".bix-td-qtxt").text
    print(question)

    # iterate over options
    for answer_block in question_block.find_elements_by_css_selector(".bix-tbl-options tr"):
        number, answer = answer_block.find_elements_by_css_selector(".bix-td-option")

        print(number.text, answer.text)

    # get answer
    answer = question_block.find_element_by_css_selector(".jq-hdnakq").get_attribute("value")
    print("Correct Answer: " + answer)

    print("----")

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
The part of machine level instruction, which tells the central processor what has to be done, is
A. Operation code
B. Address
C. Locator
D. Flip-Flop
E. None of the above
Correct Answer: A
----
Which of the following refers to the associative memory?
A. the address of the data is generated by the CPU
B. the address of the data is supplied by the users
C. there is no need for an address i.e. the data is used as an address
D. the data are accessed sequentially
E. None of the above
Correct Answer: C
----
...
Process is
A. program in High level language kept on disk
B. contents of main memory
C. a program in execution
D. a job in secondary memory
E. None of the above
Correct Answer: C
----
```