# Access code in Firefox Inspector with Python

Tags: javascript, python, firefox

I'm learning scraping with Python. I use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to extract information from the source code. However, I see that not all the information that are available in `Firefox Inspector` are reported in the source code. Why is it the case?

Comment: Because JavaScript

Comment: That's interesting! Is there a way to import it anyway? I tried using `selenium` but it didn't work (maybe because I'm new to it) @jDo

Comment: Typically, yes, but it depends on the site. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981597/python-beautifulsoup-text-from-the-html-web-page-not-shown-while-soup-find-al) that another user, alecxe, and I answered earlier today. It shows two different ways of scraping/de-obfuscating dynamic content. If you're lucky, you can go straight to the site's API instead of using one of these two approaches.

Comment: Hi @jDo. I'm trying to do what you suggested but when I run `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "history-bids-9315")))` I get the following an error (added in the main text). Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site has a separate JSON API for auction bids.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


data = requests.get("http://www.charitystars.com/ajax/getbidshistory?oid=9315")
data_dict = json.loads(data.text)

auction_table = soup(data_dict["html"])

for td in auction_table.find_all("td"):
    print td.get_text()

"""
28/04/2016
 andy.shirt.5

€ 120

27/04/2016
 simone.vanin

€ 60

"""
```

You can simply increment the `oid` to get all auctions. Be nice to the site though! Add delays and such so you don't end up DOSing a charity!

Comment: Another question: what is the difference between `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup` and `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` ?

Comment: @Mic `from [package/module name] import [class or function] as [whatever you like]`. Calling it `soup` is just a convention that other programmers would recognize - the name is arbitrary. It's simply a little easier/faster to type "soup" than "BeautifulSoup". You might have seen something similar with `import numpy as np` or `import matplotlib as plt`

Comment: @Mic `import bs4; bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text)`is the same as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; BeautifulSoup(data.text)` is the same as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as blabla; blabla(data.text)`